# Array being passed by reference when I specifically say I don't want it to

Tags: javascript, arrays, pass-by-reference

I am writing a function to work out the determinant of a matrix. The algorithm itself is irrelevant, but if you're interested, it can be found at the bottom of [this page](http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/determ1/determ1.html).

```
function det(matrix) {
    var dim = validate(matrix); // this function checks if it's an actual matrix and returns its dimensions as [rows, columns]
    if(dim && dim[0] === dim[1]) {
        var ord = dim[0];
        if(ord === 2) {
            return matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1] - matrix[0][1] * matrix[1][0]; // easy
        } else {
            var r = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < ord; i++) { // using the first row
                var elem = matrix[i][0],
                    mod = Math.pow(-1, i + 2);
                    minor = matrix.slice(0);
                console.log(ord);
                minor.splice(i, 1); // remove the ith column
                for(var j = 0; j < ord - 1; j++) {
                    minor[j].splice(0, 1); // remove the first row
                }
                r += elem * mod * det(minor);
            }
            return r;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

There is a problem: I have an array `matrix` which I want to represent the original matrix at all times, i.e. I do not want it to be modified. When I make a copy of it, I write `var minor = matrix.slice(0);` to create a new array and stop `matrix` being passed by reference. Surely this means that `minor` is a separate object? Apparently not. I do not reference `matrix` at any further point in the `else` branch, yet, somewhere, it gets modified. Through bruteforceesque `console.log`ging, I have narrowed it down to this line:

```
minor[j].splice(0, 1); // remove the first row
```

but why? Why does this line, which in no way references `matrix` end up changing its value? Surely it should only change the value of `minor`? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It's two dimensional array. You slice outer array, but row-arrays keep being the same objects.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko If that is true, that feature sounds... well, stupid. What possible reason could there be for doing that? Well, I guess I'll have to deal with it. How can I get around this?

Comment: [JS does not have "pass by reference"](http://whatsthepointy.blogspot.com.es/2013/11/javascript-does-not-have-pass-by.html). It only has "pass by value". In the case of objects, that value is a reference to the object.

Comment: @Bluefire: What feature do you mean, `slice`? Well, JS doesn't really have multidimensional arrays either, you are just using an array that contains arrays here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript arrays are one-dimensional – your matrices are arrays of arrays. When you call `slice`, you create a shallow copy. That is, you are making a new outer array that contains exactly the same inner arrays. You want to make a deep copy that also creates new inner arrays.

```
function cloneMatrix (matrix) {
    return matrix.map(function(sub) { return sub.slice(0); });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that clears up a lot. Also thank you for the snippet.

Comment: Actually, I have another question: is it possible to extend this function to an n-dimensional array?

Comment: @Bluefire `return Array.isArray(matrix) ? matrix.map(cloneMatrix) : matrix`

Comment: @Oriol Neat! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this line:

> return matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1] - matrix[0][1] * matrix[1][0]; // easy

I'm inferring that the value of each item in the array is another array.

So:

- `matrix` is a variable with the value "Reference to some array"
- `minor` is a variable with the value "Reference to an array that is a duplicate of the first array"
- `matrix[0]` is a value "Reference to another array"
- `minor[0]` is a variable that is a copy of `matrix[0]`, so it is a reference to the same array. (And the same applies for each other index).

You need to make a copy of *all* of your arrays.

Comment: Thanks, that explanation makes sense. I don't see why JS would want to do this, but I guess I can't do much about it.